# What kind of data stored in pre-trained model, such as caffe model zoo?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I came across this question from reading [squeeze net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07360) paper. The authors state that they use [Deep Compression](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00149) to compress the pre-trained model. The algorithm includes Huffman Code etc.

I infer the pre-trained are all parameters and I do know these parameters are generated when training the network but I have no idea how the parameters are generated. What role do parameters of the pre-trained model play when doing prediction?

It sounds to me like black magic

Answer (score 0):

The pre-trained model consists of the weights for *all* of the layer connections to/from every kernel of every layer.  That's the "heavy lifting" from the first 40-80 epochs of training.  It should be ready to do predictions, or continue with whatever fine-tuning you'd care to apply.

It's not really black magic.  Each framework has a facility to dump (back-up) the parameter values at specified intervals and at completion of training.  Granted, these are relatively large files -- hence the use of compression.  Each framework has a facility to read in such a dump file in order to bootstrap a model.

Comment: Can you name some papers or keyword I can search for? I don't know what kind of keyword can find the related topic ;(

Comment: (1) Off-site resources are beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.  (2) What are you trying to learn here?  If you're unfamiliar with the workings of a CNN, then look for an introduction to neural networks that includes forward-backward propagation.